# psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "trifacta" and Ident authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-hba.conf

When I try to login to postgres I get the following error:

```
# psql -U trifacta -h 127.0.0.1 trifacta
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "trifacta"

# psql -d trifacta -U trifacta -w
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "trifacta"
```

I have added trifacta user into pg_hba.conf. below is the pg_hba.conf script

```
local trifacta trifacta md5
host trifacta trifacta 127.0.0.1/32 md5
host trifacta trifacta ::1/128 md5

# Entries for trifactaactiviti user

local trifacta-activiti trifactaactiviti md5
host trifacta-activiti trifactaactiviti 127.0.0.1/32 md5
host trifacta-activiti trifactaactiviti ::1/128 md5


###### TRIFACTA ENTRIES - END ######


# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

[list of roles and dbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysUdV.jpg)

I have tested by changing md5 to peer and trust and still had the same issue. I don't know what else I can try here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it asking you for the password?

Comment: nope it doesn't ask for password. 
If I use command #sudo -u trifacta -P psql postgres then it directly takes me to postgres but I am trying to login with username and password which is required for one of application

Comment: change `-w` to `-W`

Comment: @eurotrash still same error 
# psql -d trifacta -U trifacta -W
Password for user trifacta:
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "trifacta"

Comment: so if you enter this: `psql -d trifacta -U trifacta -W` and then enter your password at the prompt, it doesn't work? Assuming you do in fact have a database and role with those names and the server is running locally.

Comment: @eurotrash nope, it doens't work. Yes they do exist, check https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysUdV.jpg

Comment: Perhaps something like: `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE trifacta TO trifacta;`

Comment: @JimJones executed the given statement and I am still executing the same error

Comment: Well, so my last guess would be that your `pg_hba.conf` isn't updated in the system. Execute the following query and try to connect again: `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

Comment: @JimJones executed the select command and restarted the server as well but still getting the same error